# Call a rule in Prolog

Tags: prolog, combinatorics, knights-tour

I'm trying to solve Knight Tour problem.
I want to call a rule to evaluate possible movements, but I can't do that my rule returns the next position in the variable that I send.

```
    move(X,Y):-
      X is X+1,
      Y is Y-2.
    move(X,Y):-
      X is X+2,
      Y is Y-1.
```

In the console I send move(2,2) for example and I hope that returns 3,0 and 4,1 but returns false.

Comment: Try `move(X,Y,X1,Y1) :- X1 is X+1, Y1 is Y-2.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use new variables and add new parameters like:

```
move(X, Y, New_X, New_Y):-
      New_X is X+1,
      New_Y is Y-2.
```

That's because when you call  move(2,2) X and Y are instantiated to the value 2 and they can't change, so you could pass two new uninstantiated variables which will be returned instantiated.

For example now if you call: `move(2,2,X,Y)`
X,Y will be instantiated (when predicate returns/succeeds) and the predicate will return you the right values in X,Y .

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer provided by @coder (+s(0)), I would suggest the use of library(clpfd), a pair representation for the coordinates and a name that reflects which argument is what, e.g. from_to/2. Then your predicate could look something like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

from_to(X-Y,X1-Y1):-
   X1 #= X+1,
   Y1 #= Y-2.
from_to(X-Y,X1-Y1):-
   X1 #= X+2,
   Y1 #= Y-1.
```

Using clpfd makes it possible to use the predicate both ways, e.g.: *I'm at position 3-4, where can I move to?*

```
   ?- from_to(3-4,T).
T = 4-2 ? ;
T = 5-3
```

Or: *I'm at position 3-4, where could I have come from?*

```
   ?- from_to(F,3-4).
F = 2-6 ? ;
F = 1-5
```

The latter case doesn't work if you define your predicate using is/2, since in that case the expression on the right side is expected to be instantiated:

```
   ?- X is 3+4.
X = 7
   ?- 7 is X+4.
     ERROR!!
     INSTANTIATION ERROR- in arithmetic: expected bound value
   ?- 7 is 3+X.
     ERROR!!
     INSTANTIATION ERROR- in arithmetic: expected bound value
```